# Search in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query

```
$objects = Object::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                ->where('object_name','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")
                ->get();
```

This returns all objects for the current user containing the keyword. This only searches for the keyword in the `object_name` column.

As I want to search within both `object_name` and `object_description`, I added an `orWhere` clause as follows:

```
 $objects = Object::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->where('object_name','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")
            ->orWhere('object_description','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")
            ->get();
```

Now this returns all the objects containing the keyword in `object_name` or `object_description`, but it does search **within the entire userbase**.

What I want is to change this query so that I can search for the keyword in `object_name` or `object_description`, but the scope for the search must be limited to the current logged in user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change your query like this

```php
$search = $request->search;
$objects = Object::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->where(function($query) use ($search) {
         $query->where('object_name','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
             ->orWhere('object_description','LIKE',"%{$search}%");
      })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works. Was not aware this was possible actually.